# Can I convert a volume from journaled to non journaled without formatting it?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, filesystem, disk-format

I have an external hard drive with HFS+ journaled. I have read that for some intrinsic reason, on a Linux machine I will not be able to write on such disk (while I am already able to read from it), as long as it is "journaled".
However, I read that the Linux system would be able to read *and* write on it if it was HFS+ *non-journaled*.

So, this is the motivation of the question: can I just convert the filesystem from HFS+ journaled to HFS+ non-journaled without formatting (and loosing all the data)?

--
Addendum: from comments I understand that I can mount the journaled volume with some special tool, from the command line, and make it writable. However the accepted answer allows the Linux system to mount the volume automatically: much better for a lazy guy like me ;)

Comment: Do you have a link/reference for the "Linux HFS+ implementation can't write to journaled HFS" statement?

Comment: PS: https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os

Comment: Thank you nohillside, from the link you give I appreciate that I can mount the volume with some additional tools, and be able as it is. But is is much straightforward the solution suggested by @Jean_JD, which will allow the Linux system to mount the volume "automatically", without any additional commands :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can with the terminal command :

```
diskutil disablejournal diskxsy
```

where disk**x**s**y** is to be adapted with the correct values of your hfs external partition.

Comment: yes! thank you! I knew this, and then I forgot... But a memory remained, that something like this existed :)